# How do you add a input and a select field with webforms?

Tags: forms

I would like to add a select element that has an input field attached, so the user can input a value from the list without having to scroll through hundreds of options. Is this possible to do with the module webforms? I have researched it and the only thing I can find is the chosen module but I have no idea how the two integrate, and alot of people say it is incompatible in some browsers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Drupal Answers Mel.

You can use the [Select or Other](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module. When you enable it, you get another element called Select other. Please take a look at the below screenshots:

[image: Select or Other]
[image: Select or Other]

Hope that helps.